# uploading images to Cloudinary that are not on my computer

Tags: html, node.js, cloud, cloudinary

I am trying to upload images selected from my dashboard I've created to Cloudinary using nodejs. I am having some trouble with this because I need to allow users to basically select any image from their computer and upload it, without hardcoding the folder path it is going to be in. The way I have it set up right now only lets me select a file from my computer with a specified path. My front end is very straightforward:

```
<label for="image">SELECT IMAGE</label>
<input type="file" name="image" id="fileUploader" required/>
```

my backend is straight from Cloudinary, with a few simple modifications to fit my existing code which uploads the image url to DB2 (sql db):

```
app.get('/addProducts', (req, res) => {
if (userAuth == 'true') {
    var path = require('path')

        // collected image from a user
        const data = {
            image: req.query.image,
          }
          console.log(data.image)
          // upload image here
          cloudinary.uploader.upload(data.image)
          .then((result) => {
              
              console.log(result.secure_url)
              
             (sql) ......
```

this line `cloudinary.uploader.upload(data.image)` will result in an error being presented about path not found. once I put this into the line of code  `cloudinary.uploader.upload('./public/css/img/ + data.image)` it works. That cannot happen, because as I said before, it will not allow any user to select an image from their local machine and upload it.

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Formidable or Multer and Express.js to upload the file from the local filesystem and upload it to Cloudinary in Node.
Here is a blog post outlining it in steps and is using express/multer: https://cloudinary.com/blog/node_js_file_upload_to_a_local_server_or_to_the_cloud